# What is the density of the reciprocal of the set of cubes?

Tags: nt.number-theory

In his MathOverflow question "[How thick is the reciprocal of the squares?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26839/how-thick-is-the-reciprocal-of-the-squares)"  Kevin  O'Bryant asks if a certain set, the reciprocal of the set of squares (identifying sets with power series in $F_2[[x]]$), has positive density. (If I've understood correctly the current situation is that the density is thought to be $\le 1/64$.)  I was curious if anything is known about the comparable question for the reciprocal of the set of cubes.

Start with the series $1+x+x^8+x^{27}+...$  Take its reciprocal $1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+x^6-x^7+x^9-2x^{10}+3x^{11}... $ and consider the set of those $n$ for which $x^n$ has a coefficient which is odd.  This sequence begins with:
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20, 23, 29, 32, 34, 35, 37, 45, 47, 48, 49, 53, 54, 57, 58, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 85, 86, 99, 101,...

Examination of the first 25,000 shows that thus far the density seems to be about $.27$.

It looks to me that one might have a chance of categorizing those numbers in this sequence which are even.  In particular it seems that numbers of the form $2k^3$, $4k^3$,... are there.

Comment: where does 1/64 come from? I thought it is known to be less than 1/16, and two available conjectures think it to be 0 or 1/32? or has something changed since 2010?

Comment: @dotsenko:  I believe that 1/64 is what Kevin O'Bryant told me in a conversation last week, but I could be misremembering.

Comment: It'd be interesting to have a confirmation of that if it is really the case. (My main references to date are http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3985 and http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.4137).

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko I think  the person to ask is Paul Monsky.

Comment: It seems that the even numbers in the sequence mentioned are numbers which can be written in an odd number of ways as a sum 2a^3+4b^3, where a and b are non-negative numbers.